# Spring Boot Admin- OAuth2 Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-admin

currently I'm working on spring boot admin and trying to monitor my REST APIs which I've written in Spring Boot and secured them with **OAuth2**.

Now I want to monitor my APIs with spring boot admin, how do I do that?

Comment: Additionally it shows my application always OFFLINE. I'm using 1.5.6 version